# How does one get the metadata of each band of a grib file using rasterio?

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, metadata, grib

Is there a way to see the metadata of each band of a grib file using `rasterio`? Using `gdal` this can be accomplished by:

```
import gdal

path = r"D:\path\to\somewhere.grib"

ds = gdal.Open(path)  

for band in range(1, ds.RasterCount):
    print(ds.GetRasterBand(band).GetMetadata())
```

an example of one band's metadata from a GFS grib using the method above is as follows

```
{'GRIB_COMMENT': 'Temperature [C]', 'GRIB_DISCIPLINE': '0(Meteorological)', 'GRIB_ELEMENT': 'TMP', 'GRIB_FORECAST_SECONDS': '21600 sec', 'GRIB_IDS': 'CENTER=7(US-NCEP) SUBCENTER=0 MASTER_TABLE=2 LOCAL_TABLE=1 SIGNF_REF_TIME=1(Start_of_Forecast) REF_TIME=2022-02-02T06:00:00Z PROD_STATUS=0(Operational) TYPE=1(Forecast)', 'GRIB_PDS_PDTN': '0', 'GRIB_PDS_TEMPLATE_ASSEMBLED_VALUES': '0 0 2 0 96 0 0 1 6 1 0 0 255 0 0', 'GRIB_PDS_TEMPLATE_NUMBERS': '0 0 2 0 96 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 6 1 0 0 0 0 0 255 0 0 0 0 0', 'GRIB_REF_TIME': '  1643781600 sec UTC', 'GRIB_SHORT_NAME': '0-SFC', 'GRIB_UNIT': '[C]', 'GRIB_VALID_TIME': '  1643803200 sec UTC'}
```

I'm trying to get this same information but using `rasterio` instead. Is this possible? So far I've tried

```
import rasterio 

with rasterio.open(file) as src:
    print(src.descriptions)
    print(src.meta)
    print(src.profile)
```

with the closest being `src.descriptions`. However, it only gave the following

```
('0[-] SFC="Ground or water surface"')
```

It seems to be only getting a piece of the metadata. Does anyone know how to get the rest?

Comment: Could you share a file that we can test on our side ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get those using the `tags` method.

```py
import rasterio 

with rasterio.open(input_file) as src:
    print(src.tags(band_number))
```

Comment: This worked, thank you!